# Insert a line of text before lines matching a regex in vim

Tags: vim, html, regex

I'm attempting to add a column to an HTML table using vim so I need to add a pair of `<td>` tags the line before each `</tr>`. So far I have

`:186,$s/  <\/tr>/<td><\/td> \n  <\/tr>/g`
but vim shows `^@` instead of making a new line for the closing tr tag. Is there any way around that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `\r` instead of `\n` in the replacement part, a quirk of Vim's `:s` command. And you can further simplify the command by using a different separator, e.g. `#`, and by referring to the match via `&`:

```
:186,$s# </tr>#<td></td> \r&#g
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm a little confused because I thought that \n was the linux newline character and \r\n was for windows. Also, what does it mean to "refer to the match with &?

Comment: That's explained at `:h s/\r` and `:h s/\&`, resp. The `&` contains the match, i.e. `</tr>`, so you don't need to repeat it. You could also use an assertion with `\zs`, but that's even more advanced...